# How can I use a custom source model for a multiselect product attribute in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, source-model

I've created an attribute in Magento 2 of the type `multiselect` and now I want to have it populated by a custom source model.

Now I remember from Magento 1 that when you want to do this, you had to manually edit the attribute in the database and set the `source_model` to the path of the source model.

However, when I do this in Magento 2, I get an error. I changed `source_model` in `eav_attribute` to `Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Product\Attributes`, but when I want to edit the product in the admin, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Product\Attributes::setAttribute() in .../vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:547

Stack trace: #0 .../var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php(1129): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource()
#1 .../vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(232): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getSource()
#2 .../vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_applyTypeSpecificConfig('multiselect', Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Multiselect), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor))
#3 .../vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(51): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\El in .../vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php on line 547
```

Does anyone know how I can create a product attribute with a custom source model?

**Edit:**

Current Source Model:

```
use Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\AbstractSource;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\TypeFactory;

/**
 * Class Attributes
 */
class Attributes extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeFactory
     */
    protected $attributeFactory;

    /**
     * @var TypeFactory
     */
    protected $eavTypeFactory;

    /**
     * Attributes constructor.
     * @param AttributeFactory $attributeFactory
      @param TypeFactory $typeFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        AttributeFactory $attributeFactory,
        TypeFactory $typeFactory
    )
    {
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        $this->eavTypeFactory = $typeFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $arr = [];

        $entityType = $this->eavTypeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product');        
        $collection = $this->attributeFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityType->getId());
        $collection->setOrder('attribute_code');

        /** @var Attribute $attribute */
        foreach ($collection as $attribute) {
            $arr[$attribute->getAttributeId()] = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
        }

        return $arr;
    }
}
```

Class `Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\AbstractSource`:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

abstract class AbstractSource implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * Options getter
     * @return array
     */
    final public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $arr = $this->toArray();
        $ret = [];

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your current source model code.

Comment: I've added my source model and the abstract class it extends. The abstract class is nothing more than a method that generates the `toOptionArray()` output.

Answer (score 6):

I got it! It turns out that multiselect uses the backend model `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend`. For this reason, the source model, must also take EAV into account. How can we do this? Simple: just extend your source model from `Attribute\Source\AbstractSource` and implement the `getAllOptions()`-method (which returns a 2-dimensional array with `value` and `label`-keys:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $arr = $this->toArray();
    $ret = [];

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $ret[] = [
            'value' => $key,
            'label' => $value
        ];
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

That's it! Enjoy using your custom source model for multiselect attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm
 * User: moazzam
 * Date: 31/10/22
 * Time: 7:59 AM
 */

namespace NbrolMarket\LocalMarket\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
use NbrolMarket\LocalMarket\Model\ResourceModel\Market\CollectionFactory as MarketCollectionFactory;

/**
 * Create market options
 *
 * Class MarketOptions
 */
class MarketOptions extends AbstractSource
{
    /**
     * @var MarketCollectionFactory
     */
    private MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->marketCollectionFactory = $marketCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve All options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $marketCollection = $this->marketCollectionFactory->create();
        $marketCollection->addFieldToSelect("*")->load()->getItems();

        if ($marketCollection->getSize() > 0){
            $options[] = ['label' => __('--Select--'), 'value' => ''];
            foreach ($marketCollection as $markets){
                $name =  __($markets->getData('name'));
                $code =  $markets->getData("code");
                $options[] = [
                    'label'=> $name ,'value'=> $code
                ];
            }
            return $options;
        }
    }
}
```